# How to: Send collection of objects over a socket?

Tags: java, network-programming, biginteger

Suppose I want to send a collection of objects over a network via a socket in Java. For concreteness, suppose I want to send an array of `BigInteger` objects. The sender should simply send this array in one chunk over the socket, so that the receiver could cast the received object to the proper form.

*How can this be accomplished ?*

I've tried using `ObjectOutputStream` to send this array of objects. However, it doesn't go as planned.

Some of the code:

```
        BigInteger[] bigIntegers = new BigInteger[10];
        bigIntegers[0] = new BigInteger("0");
        bigIntegers[1] = new BigInteger("1");
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeObject(bigIntegers);
```

I assume that the underlying architecture is the same at both ends.

Can someone show how to send such a collection of objects, as well as receive this collection on the other side of the socket?

Thanks,

Comment: `However, it doesn't go as planned.`. What was the plan?

Comment: Simply to send this array to the other side of the socket, so that the other side could cast it to an BigInteger[] if that's possible ?

Comment: Please describe your expectations, and what was the actual outcome that did not fulfill your expectations. Additionally, I think you should also post the code on "the other side".

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Before we can comment on whether it's possible, we need to see what is happening currently when you try this..

Answer (score 1):

you can send objects to server socket using

```
objectOut.writeObject(bigIntegers);
objectOut.flush();
```

and can retrieve that object at server side using
here `client` is clientsocket

```
ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
BigInteger[] array = (BigInteger[]) objectIn.readObject();
```

Comment: Just to be sure, what is the type of objectIn here ? -- Is it an ObjectInputStream ?

Comment: I must do a stupid mistake then somewhere in my code, I will look it up. What is the benefits of using the lower level byte streams, if one can just send objects like this ?

Comment: The ObjectInputStream class enables you to read Java objects from InputStream's instead of only bytes. You wrap an InputStream in a ObjectInputStream and then you can read objects from it. reference from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/objectinputstream.html) .